chmod +x approach to run script in YML Azure Devops
I have started to practice how to create yml in azure devops. I have the following simple example I did.
azure-pipelines.yml
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

parameters:
- name: name
  type: string

trigger:
- master

pool:
 vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  fetchTags: true
  clean: true

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Run hello script'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      chmod +x "./scripts/hello.sh"
      ./scripts/hello.sh  ${{ parameters.name}}
  continueOnError: false


hello.sh
#!/bin/sh

# Parameters
NAME=$1

echo "Hello $NAME, this is a script"

What I would like to know?
Adding  chmod +x "./scripts/hello.sh" is a good approach? Because when I don't add this I always get "script has no permission"
error. Once I run the pipeline with that line it works properly.
Why I ask this?
I have been researching a lot about YML examples on internet and I never saw they add that chmod +x "script_name" line so that's why I'm curious about it..

When calling a Bash script file (.sh) from the source repository in Azure Pipeline, you do not need to use the command "chmod +x" to assign access to the script file. you can directly call the script file on the Bash task with the 'filePath' type.
parameters:
- name: name
  type: string
  default: 'xxxx'

trigger:
- master

pool:
 vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  . . .

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Run hello script'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: 'scripts/hello.sh'
    arguments: '"${{ parameters.name }}"'


Thanks Bright! What if I want to capture the output of my script file and save it into a global variable that is located in my yml file? I used to do it this way:
script: |
chmod +x "./scripts/my-script.sh"
output=$(./scripts/my-script.sh $(FIRST_PARAMETER))
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GLOBAL_VARIABLE]$output"
How can I do it now using filePath?

I found out that putting the following line in my script file works.. you think it is a good approach?
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GLOBAL_VARIABLE]$output

@depreston, Yes, using the logging command 'SetVariable' to set the output in script is a recommended way in Azure Pipelines.
